# Include .thrift File from External Repository

Tags: sbt, thrift

I have an Sbt project "A" with an `A.thrift` file. I need to `include` a `B.thrift` file in the definition of the `A.thrift` file. The problem is that the `B.thrift` file resides in an external repository / Sbt project "B". What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You mean, like including an include file where a physical file is expected but without having a physical file?

Comment: @JensG yes, basically importing a thrift definition from an external jar into a thrift file. Apparently, it is much easier than I thought, and putting it into the `resources` like with other files does the trick. I just thought that thrift would not read it from the claspath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that I needed to do to solve this.
First, I needed to add `Compile / scroogePublishThrift := true` and `Compile / scroogeThriftSourceFolder := file('path/to/the/thrift/files')` configuration to the "B" Sbt project to include raw thrift files as sources to the jar.
Second, I needed to add `Compile / scroogeThriftDependencies   := Seq("projectB_2.12")` (where "projectB_2" is the GroupId of the project "B") in the "A" sbt project to set a dependency on the "B" project.